# Issue with bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to run an old project but I have problem. I'm using:

- Ruby - 1.9.3
- Rails - 3.0.20

I'm getting the following error while installing the gems. How do I install these gems?

```
Resolving dependencies...................................................................................................................
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    active_form was resolved to 1.0.4, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)

    active_form was resolved to 1.0.4, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)

    paper_trail (~> 3.0.1) was resolved to 3.0.9, which depends on
      activesupport (< 5.0, >= 3.0)

    paperclip was resolved to 4.3.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)

    rails (= 3.0.20) was resolved to 3.0.20, which depends on
      activesupport (= 3.0.20)

    rails (= 3.0.20) was resolved to 3.0.20, which depends on
      activesupport (= 3.0.20)

    rails (= 3.0.20) was resolved to 3.0.20, which depends on
      activesupport (= 3.0.20)

    rails (= 3.0.20) was resolved to 3.0.20, which depends on
      activesupport (= 3.0.20)

    rails (= 3.0.20) was resolved to 3.0.20, which depends on
      activesupport (= 3.0.20)

    rspec-rails (~> 2.14.0) was resolved to 2.14.2, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you carefully read the explanation, it's quite clear where the problem is.

```
paperclip was resolved to 4.3.1, which depends on
  activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
```

This specific gem requires an `activesupport` version which is at least 3.2, but your project has Rails (and consequently `activesupport`) freezed at 3.0.20.

You need to use a `paperclip` version which is compatible with older versions of Rails. Edit your `Gemfile` and specify an older `paperclip` version.

You can check the [paperclip dependencies on RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip) and select the proper version.

Answer (score 0):

You should decrease your `paperclip` gem version.